# Does model.save_weights(save_format='tf') save the Optimizer state?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to implement a `Keras` based U-Net model in `TF2.1`. I have written a custom loss-function for this purpose. My aim was to save the model/its weights at the end of each `epoch`. For this, I am using [`tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint).

```
tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath, monitor='val_loss', verbose=0, save_best_only=False,
    save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', save_freq='epoch', options=None, **kwargs
)
```

In order to continue training at a later time, I need to save the `optimizer` state. The sure way to save the `optimizer` state is to pass `save_weights_only=False`, and use the `'tf'` or `'h5'` save_format to save the entire model. I read [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#whole-model_saving_loading), that Tensorflow `SavedModel` format is the recommended method to save models. But, for some reason, using that format takes a lot of time, whenever the model is being saved at the end of each (On the other hand, `save_format='h5'` saves the entire model pretty fast). Now, when I pass `save_weights_only=True` with `'tf'` format, it saves the weights as Checkpoints. I was wondering, if `save_weights_only=True, save_format='tf'` also saves the `optimizer` state? [As far as I know, `save_weights_only=True, save_format='h5'` only saves the weights and not the optimizer.]

I would be glad, if someone could clarify this, or point if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: No, the optimizer won't be saved in that case. I found it much better to use `tf.train.Checkpoint` and `tf.train.CheckpointManager` in a custom callback rather than `tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint`